# how to use sed and regex to trim the prefix and suffix with a special character in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I tried with the following sed command to remove the prefix and suffix with the `_` character. However, it removed to the last _. Can someone help?

```
Input: abc_exa_mp_le_1.1
```

Tried the following sed

```
x= bc_exa_mp_le_1.1
$ z="$(sed -e 's/.*_\(.*\)\.*/\1/' <<<"$x")"
$ echo "$z"
1.1
Expected output:exa_mp_le
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Use `z="$(sed -e 's/^[^_]*_\(.*\)_.*/\1/' <<< "$x")"`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
z="$(sed 's/^[^_]*_\(.*\)_.*/\1/' <<< $x)"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Pr8PCS).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore
- `\(.*\)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this part of the matched text): any 0+ chars
- `_` - an underscore
- `.*` -  any 0+ chars up to the end of the line.

Comment: Perhaps `0+` should read `zero or more` and that `*`  is greedy and consumes as many matches as possible i.e. `.*` matches the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in pure bash also:

```
x="bc_exa_mp_le_1.1"
z="${s%_*}"
z="${s#*_}"
echo "$z"
```

```
exa_mp_le
```

You can use a simpler `sed` also:

```
z=$(sed -E 's/^[^_]*_|_[^_]*$//g' <<< "$x")
```

This `sed` command first strips everything till first `_` and then it removes part starting from last `_` in input string.